# 'Possible overdraw' when adding ripple effect to RecyclerView item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

After creating my RecyclerView, I noticed this warning appear when trying to apply the ripple effect to my RecyclerView item layout. Why does this warning occur when in various tutorials `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` is what they tell people to use to get the ripple effect? Does anyone know what should be done to get rid of this warning?

> Possible overdraw: Root element paints background '?attr/selectableItemBackground' with a theme that also paints a background (inferred theme is '@style/AppTheme')

**RecyclerView item layout (XML)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_RVItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
```

**related theme in styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

**app defined in the Manifest**

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a warning that is, in this case, something you should ignore.

The linter is *trying* to find cases where your Activity's theme specifies a `windowBackground` attribute, but *also* has a root view that specifies a `background` attribute. In these cases, the entire background of the screen will be drawn once for the `windowBackground`, and then completely painted over again for the `background`.

In these real cases, you should remove the root view's `background` attribute and set the Activity's theme's `windowBackground` to what you had on the root view.

But you're not doing that here. First of all, this is just an itemView, not an Activity. And second of all, the ripple effect will normally *not* obscure the background "below" the view.

Comment: Also keep in mind that lint is stupid. It can be incredibly helpful, but it doesn't know what you're trying to do. It only sees what's right in front of its face, and not necessarily what will be in front of the user's face.